# Inline Editing Lookup field in Lightning Data table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience

I have a lightning data table displaying set of Account Records. Also it have inline editing set true for all the columns.

Is it possible to have Account name field to behave like a lookup field and not a normal text field while editing.

Note: I already have a custom lookup component.(in lwc). all I need is guidance how to implement the lookup field inside the lightning datable.

My Cmp code.

```
   <div style="height: 500px">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="acctList"
                         keyField="Id"
                         columns="{! v.columns }"
                         data="{! v.filteredData }"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                         sortedBy="{!v.sortBy}"
                         sortedDirection="{!v.sortDirection}"
                         onsort="{!c.handleSort}"
                         onsave="{! c.onSave }"/>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
       
        {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',sortable : true,editable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank',tooltip: { fieldName: 'Name' }}},
        {label: 'Account Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'url',sortable : true,editable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'OwnerName' }, target: '_blank',tooltip: { fieldName: 'OwnerName' }}},
        {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone',  type: 'Phone',editable: true},
        {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website',  type: 'url',editable: true},
        {label: 'Annual revenue', fieldName: 'AnnualRevenue', type: 'currency',editable: true},
    ]);
helper.onLoadAcc(component, event, helper);
},
```

Helper:

```
  onLoadAcc : function(component,event,helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(resp) {
        if (resp.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
            var rows = resp.getReturnValue();
            console.log("Account Values"+ JSON.stringify(rows));
            rows.forEach(function(record){
                record['OwnerName'] = record.Owner.Name;
            });
                rows.forEach(function(record){
                record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
            });
            component.set('v.data', rows );
            component.set('v.filteredData', rows );
        }
        
    }) ;    
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sfdcpanther has the answer! With a full walkthrough of how to extend the lightning data table into a custom component so that you can put in your own components, or use the examples they gave.

At a high level, you can extend the lightning data table component into a custom lwc, build in your custom types that point to separate lwc's, such as a lookup type that points to a lwc-lookup component.

```js
export default class ExtendedDataTable extends LightningDatatable

static customTypes = {
    lookup : {
        template: lookupTemplate,
        typeAttributes: ['object', 'icon', 'label', 'placeholder', 'fields', 'displayFields', 'valueId', 'valueName','currentRecordId'],
    }
};
```

Then generate a new html file named `lwclookup` inside your extended component that instantiates your custom component for lookups as outlined by this [sfdcpanther article](https://www.sfdcpanther.com/how-to-use-the-lookup-field-in-lightning-datatable/).

For an example, here is the direct link to the [github repo](https://github.com/amitastreait/Salesforce-Short-Hands/tree/master/sfdxsrc/lightningDataTable)